# Adding custom basemap in ArcGIS.Com that can be used in Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, basemap

It's possible to add a layer as a basemap in ArcGIS.com by checking the check box use as baselayer:

[image: Use as base Layer]

But when I consume the map using:

```
var mapDeferred = esri.arcgis.utils.createMap("<guid>", "map", {
                mapOptions: {
                    slider: true,
                    nav: false
                }
            });
```

the basemap don't show up, is there any rules that define what content can be used as a basemap?

Comment: one quick question, after u added the required Web Service as basemap, were you able to customize it and enable popups on it? In the same manner as we can do when we add a simple shapefile and then enable popups on it. I tried but it seems that if you want to add a shapefile as a basemap, the enable popup feature is no more available. This is the question that I posted, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31825/arcgis-online-without-basemap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible, here's an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.5/js/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.5/js/esri/dijit/css/Popup.css">
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
    <script>var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };</script>
    <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.5"></script>
    <script>
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
      dojo.require("esri.map");
      dojo.require("esri.arcgis.utils");

      var map;
      esri.config.defaults.geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService('http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer');
      function init() {
        var agol_map = new esri.arcgis.utils.createMap("c11215b898ec46369f855c82b28fc65e", "map", {
          mapOptions: {
            slider: true,
            nav:false
          }
        });
        agol_map.addCallback(function(response) {
          // Keep a reference to the map
          map = response.map;

          dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', function() { 
            dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', map, map.resize);
          });
        });
      }
      dojo.ready(init);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="tundra">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" 
         data-dojo-props="design:'headline',gutters:false" 
         style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
      <div id="map" 
           data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" 
           data-dojo-props="region:'center'"> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update:**
The key is to add a default geometry service:

```
esri.config.defaults.geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService('http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer');
```