# Using download JavaScript code option of ArcGIS Online without getting basemap too?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I am trying to create a Web App, using the ArcGIS Online feature of downloading the javascript code, with the map id being used for connecting to the ArcGIS Online. I was able to do that successfully but the only issue is that I do not want a basemap. I only want the overlaying shapefile to be visible. How can I do that? Or is it not possible?

ArcGIS Online does provides an option, where I can make my shapefile as the basemap and then the features of popups cannot be used on it. Any ideas how I can work it out?

Comment: the answer is cross-posted on the [Esri forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/65114-Trying-to-obtain-Javascript-code-from-ArcGIS-Online-without-having-any-basemap) - call basemap.hide

Answer (score 3):

Without looking at your code and knowing what end-result you're actually going for, I think the easiest solution is to just edit your JavaScript code and omit adding the basemap into your map object. Most basemap calls look like one of these two lines:

```
map.addLayer(basemap);
map.addLayers([basemap, myData, otherLayers, mapIsGettingCrowded]);
```

(Note the plural when adding more than one map)

Removing/editing whichever line is relevant should remove the basemap from your Web App.